# kernel parameters + what is the right way to refresh the kernel parameter from custom.conf after reboot

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

we set the following kernel parameters in file `99-custom.conf`

```
more /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf

net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 5
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
```

in order to set on the fly, the parameters above we can use `sysctl -p  /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf`

but after reboot of course the values will disappear.

so, one way to solved this is to set the following in `/etc/rc.local`

as

```
more /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/bash
# THIS FILE IS ADDED FOR COMPATIBILITY PURPOSES
#
# It is highly advisable to create own systemd services or udev rules
# to run scripts during boot instead of using this file.
#
# In contrast to previous versions due to parallel execution during boot
# this script will NOT be run after all other services.
#
# Please note that you must run chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local to ensure
# that this script will be executed during boot.

touch /var/lock/subsys/local

sysctl -p  /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf
```

is above the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directory `/etc/sysctl.d/` exists in your Linux distribution as standard, then most likely it already has a startup script or systemd unit that does the equivalent of:

```
for i in /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
do
    sysctl -p "$i"
done
```

In other words, it is likely that there already is a script or some other feature that uses `sysctl -p` to read all `*.conf` files in the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory. But it might happen very early in the boot process, when the system is still running from initramfs, so you might need to update your initramfs after adding any files to `/etc/sysctl.d/`. Check your distribution's documentation on how to do this; the exact commands will vary between distributions.

But if you have created the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory *yourself*, then the system will not automatically read the files for you. If you only care about the one `/etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf` file, then the way you have done it in `/etc/rc.local` certainly does the job for now.

However, you might be creating a trap for yourself.

As sysadmin automation solutions like Ansible and Salt become more and more common, it has become a common pattern to replace (or augment) singular configuration files (like `/etc/<something>.conf`) with a corresponding directory into which you can drop any number of partial configuration files: for example `/etc/<something>.d/*.conf`. Normally, when such a directory is created, the system that reads that configuration is modified to read **all** the configuration files in that directory that match the pattern (so any editor backup files etc. are avoided automatically). This is sometimes called a *drop-in directory*, as you can just drop configuration snippets in there and run the command to reload the configuration/restart the service in question. That can make automated configuration management very easy.

If you create your own `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory but only configure `/etc/rc.local` to read just the one `/etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf`, you might forget about this fact. Then, some day, some new sysctl settings need to be added, and you or one of your co-workers sees `/etc/sysctl.d/`, thinks "ah, it has the new drop-in directory scheme, so I can just add my new settings to `/etc/sysctl.d/98-more-custom.conf` and I'm done"... and then gets a nasty surprise when the new settings are ignored after a reboot.

So, if you actually created the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory, I would suggest that you replace the single `sysctl -p  /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf` line in `/etc/rc.local` with the four lines at the beginning of this answer. That way, your `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory will work as expected even if more `*.conf` files are added to it.

If `/etc/sysctl.d/` was created as standard by the OS installer, but the `*.conf` files within it won't get used on boot, even after rebuilding your initramfs, you might want to send a bug report to the maintainers of the distribution about the incomplete implementation of the `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` drop-in directory pattern.